# File Handling and export into text file

Tags: c, stack, postfix-mta

I need your help please. I want to export the output of my code into a text file. and i really don't know how to deal with it. Could someone please help me figuring this out. Thank you so much

So here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node {
int data;
struct node *next;
};
struct node *top = NULL;

struct node* createNode(int data){
struct node *p = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof (struct node));
p->data = data;
p->next = NULL;
}

void push (int data){
    struct node *ptr = createNode(data);
    if (top == NULL){
        top = ptr;
    return;
    }
    ptr->next = top;
    top = ptr;
}

int pop(){
    int data;
    struct node *temp;
    if (top == NULL)
        return -1;
    data = top->data;
    temp = top;
    top =top->next;
    free(temp);
return (data);
}

int main(){
        char str[100];
        int i = 0, data = -1, operand1, operand2, result;
        printf("Expression in postfix format: ");
        fgets(str, 99, stdin);
            for (; i < strlen(str); i++){
                if (isdigit(str[i])){
                data = (data == -1) ? 0 : data;
                data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);
                continue;
            }
            if (data != -1){
            push(data);
            }
            if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/'){
            operand2 = pop();
            operand1 = pop();
                if (operand1 == -1 || operand2 == -1)
                    break;

        switch (str[i]){
            case '+':
                    result = operand1 + operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
            case '-':
                    result = operand1 - operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
            case '*':
                    result = operand1 * operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
            case '/':
                    result = operand1 / operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
                }
            }
                    data = -1;
        }
                    if (top != NULL && top->next == NULL)
                        printf("Postfix Evaluation: %d\n", top->data);
                    else
                        printf("Invalid Expression!\n");
        return 0;
```

}

Comment: You need to replace the printfs with fprintfs

Comment: `prog > output.txt`

Comment: or use `freopen`

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!.  Amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`  for the `isdigit()`

Comment: the function: `createNode()` signature says it returns a pointer to a `struct node`.  However, no such return statement exists in that function.

Comment: there's no problem with the compilation

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. 2) the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting is unneeded and just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. suggest each indent level be four spaces. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).  4) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the function: `fgets()` is smart enough to stop inputting characters while there is still room to insert a final NUL ('\0') char, so the buffer length should be the full length of the input buffer.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E, 99, 100 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful name then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Note: the function: `strlen()` return value is type `size_t` so should be compared/assigned to variables of that same type.

Comment: the function: `push()` has several logic problems.  Suggest re-designing that function

Comment: the posted code fails when the input includes expressions that include parens and when the input includes a `modulo` '%' operator. and when any numeric value is <0 and when the result of (say) a `-` results in a value of -1

Comment: @Clark,  if your compiler is not outputting several messages about problems with the code then you need to enable the warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: @user3629249 thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main you must open the file:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen ("whatever.txt", "w+"); // w+ mean that you open the file 
                                   // write and read, but if it
                                   // not exist, will be made.
```

and change the `printf` with `fprintf` :

```
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i); // you must add the name of the file where to
                        // print your stuff (fp)
```

At the end of main, remember to close the file connection:

```
fclose (fp);
```